# One to Infinity regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I am trying to validate my text box control, which should hold a number between one and infinity ( it cannot be 0 or a negative number).

I would like to use a `regularexpressionvalidator` in c#, as a `rangevalidator` asks for a maximum number when I don't want there to be one.

I was hoping if anyone could assist me to create a regular expression that checks for a number between one and infinity.

I have searched online and the closed thing I have found is `{1,}`, but this causes a `parsing "{1,}" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing` error. Not too clued up on regular expressions but was hoping someone could help me find an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just need a whole number,

```
[1-9][0-9]*
```

should have you covered. That's "a non-zero digit, followed by any number of digits".

If you don't want to reject e.g. `04546`, something like

```
0*[1-9][0-9]*
```

should do it. (Same as above, preceded by zero or more zeroes.)

Comment: In the second case, just do `[0-9]+`

Comment: @RenéWolferink That would let `0` slide through, wouldn't it?

Comment: it should be `^[1-9][0-9]*` otherwise leading zero will pass

Comment: @Kyobul ASP.NET's `RegularExpressionValidator` checks not only that a match exists, but that it starts at 0 and is the length of the input - so there's no need for `^` and `$`.

Comment: @Rawling, you are certainly right but in my case, using PHP > 5.4, leading zeros pass without ^ $

Comment: @Kyobul Of course, but that's an answer to *your* question, not the question to which this is an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This would do it:

```
[1-9][0-9]*
```

One or more digits, excluding 0.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`CompareValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with`ValueToCompare=0` and `Operator="GreaterThan"`.

You can also use `compareValidator` to check if number is an Integer, with `Operator="DataTypeCheck"`

Comment: This seems ideal... Presumably you need to tell it to expect an integer (or float) somehow, so it doesn't perform e.g. a string comparison?

Comment: Yes, there is `Type` property as well, which indicates what type should be expected in the field.

Answer (score 1):

assuming an Integer something like

[1-9][0-9]*

should be ok

Answer (score 1):

I tested `[1-9][0-9]*` and it turns out that it matches strings like "1d", "5h".

So, I used this one, `^[1-9][0-9]*$`, it matches only whole numbers from 1 to infinity.